# Unable to connect to WiFi via NetworkManager sometimes(!)

Tags: wireless-networking, arch-linux, ipv6, xfce, networkmanager

I have an issue which occurs only in Arch + Xfce + NetworkManager.
It doesn't occur in Arch + Gnome + NetworkManager or in Ubuntu or Arch + Xfce + wicd on my machine if I'm not missing something.

When I'm trying to connect to some(!) wifi access points, I'm unable to and the following messages appear in dmesg:

```
[27524.388055] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[27524.561891] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[27524.970483] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[27525.146824] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
................

[27478.260413] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
[27509.173365] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[27509.639527] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[27524.388055] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[27524.561891] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[27524.970483] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[27525.146824] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[27539.858535] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
................



[ 8380.749651] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[ 8380.934894] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[ 8383.002757] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
[12001.369194] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[12001.796397] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[12009.764741] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[12010.196863] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[12010.369083] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready

................
```

I tried turning off IPv6 but that didn't help. And I've also tried "ip link set wlp4s0 up/down" and similar commands.